# Use string as parameter in JSON object to retrieve the value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string:

```
str_rfrnc = '["text"]["title"]["res"]["din"]'
```

I load a json:

```
data = json.loads(myjson)
```

The below code works fine:

```
print(data["text"]["title"]["res"]["din"])
```

How to use the string for the same result as above?

```
print(data[str_rfrnc]) #This fails
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest solution that works:

```
>>> str_rfrnc = '["text"]["title"]["res"]["din"]'
>>> data = { 'text': { 'title': { 'res': { 'din': 10 } } } }
>>> eval('data' + str_rfrnc)
10
```

Note that you should use `eval` only if you trust the contents of `str_rfrnc`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that doesn't use `eval`:

```
>>> from operator import getitem
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from re import split

>>> str_rfrnc = '["text"]["title"]["res"]["din"]'
>>> data = { 'text': { 'title': { 'res': { 'din': 10 } } } }

>>> fields = split(r'[\[\]"]+', str_rfrnc)[1:-1]
>>> fields
['text', 'title', 'res', 'din']

>>> reduce(getitem, fields, data)
10
```